# How to update CSV data and send the file to an API in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv

In my application, the user uploads a CSV file in the website, and I need to update the file content (add a few columns) and send it to an API.

So far, I am able to read the file, and transform the CSV content into a JSON object, but I'm stuck in the process of updating the file content and sending it to the API (which needs to receive an object of type File). However, the way that I found is transforming the CSV into an encodeURI.

This is the code:

```
import { post } from "axios";

class UploadAdmin extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // ...
  }

  onFormSubmit(e) {
    if (this.state.file != null) {
      e.preventDefault();

      // adding the missing columns to the JSON object
      const csvObject = this.state.parsedCsvFile;
      csvObject["Campaign Name"] = this.state.campaign_name;
      csvObject["Campaign Code"] = this.state.campaign_code;

      const rows = [Object.keys(csvObject), Object.values(csvObject)];

      let csvContent =
        "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," +
        rows.map((e) => e.join(";")).join("\n");

      // creating CSV file (here the error is happening, since I need to create an object 
      // with File type to send to the fileUpload() function, but I'm creating an URI)
      var newFile = encodeURI(csvContent);

      this.fileUpload(newFile)
        .then((resp) => {
          this.onClear();
          this.setState({ modal: true, tipo: "success" });
          this.props.getListImport();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // handling errors...
    } else {
      this.onClear();
    }
  }

  fileUpload(file) {
    const BASE_URL = `${window.REACT_APP_URL}`;
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
    };
    return post(`${BASE_URL}/file`, formData, config);
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you get if you add `console.log("Error:", error);` inside the `catch` function? Or are there any messages in the browser console, particularly the Network and Console tabs? Also, is there anything interesting in the server logs?

Comment: What is `post`?

Comment: `post` is the `axios.post`method (I've updated my question). What I'm sending to the API is this: `data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,Campaign%20Code;Campaign%20Name;.....`, then I get an error because I need to send an object whose type is `File` , but as you can see, I'm sending an URI.

Comment: Are you supposed to be sending a multipart message?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I'm still confused about this, but I don't have time right now. The following may or may not work:

```
  fileUpload(file) {
    const BASE_URL = `${window.REACT_APP_URL}`;
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    searchParams.append("file", file);
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
    };
    const file = new File(searchParams.toString(), "my-file",
        { type: "multipart/form-data" });
    return post(`${BASE_URL}/file`, file, config);
  }
```

I changed the `FormData` to a `URLSearchParams`. They seem to be very similar types, but `URLSearchParams` has a `toString` method which I've called. Then I made it into a `File` because you said this was necessary, although I'm not convinced that it is. I also renamed it from `formData` to `searchParams`.